# javascript find anonymous reference

Tags: javascript

I have this inside the HTML that is creating an object in JavaScript

```
var myObject = new MyClass();
```

I know that after this I can refer to myObject and use it.

The problem is that I have the instantiation done in an anonymous way e.g.

```
new MyClass()
```

Is there a way to find then the instance so I can reuse it later in the code ? Any idea appreciated.

Comment: This question is too general to answer like this. Can you give more details? Most importantly: Why can't you chance the code to assign the object to a variable?

Comment: The part that contains "new MyClass()" is scattered through zillions of files so it would require a massive search & replace, I am looking therefore for a clean way without modifying existing files. If there's no way of cleanly do this, then I will go for search & replace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for example

```
lastOfMe = null

function myClass() {
   lastOfMe = this;
   this.x = 123;
}

new myClass();
alert(lastOfMe.x)
```

this is totally ugly though

Answer (score 2):

It depends of how MyClass works...

It could have saved all the instances in a class property, but in most cases, you must assign the result of the instantiation to a variable...

Answer (score 1):

Anonymous objects are just that. If you want to use your object again, why create it anonymously?

If you really must do this, then just ensure that your object will register itself somewhere, like as a property of a global or similar, so you can grab it later.